# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3591) into shape (3600)

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter out this signal with a moving average, but i'm having this problem:

## Media mobile filter

```
def media_movel(x, N):
    mm = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0)) 
    return (mm[N:] - mm[:-N]) / N

x_f_v = np.transpose(np.array(df_v))
N1=10
for i in range (0,np.shape(df_v.values)[1]):
    x_f_v[i] = media_movel(x_f_v[i], N1)
```